# AS3 Flash - Save movieclip as png

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, save, png

I use AS3 flash. Can someone help me? I want that if you press the save_image button, then it saves "guy" movieclip as png. But It's not work:

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder

save_image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save_image_function);
function save_image_function(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(50,50);
bmd.draw(guy);
var encorder:PNGEncoder   = new PNGEncoder();
var bytes:ByteArray = encorder.encode(bmd);
var file:FileReference    = new FileReference();
file.save( bytes, "Image.png" );
}
```

Can someone help me? The error code is this:

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property encode not found on com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder and there is no default value.
>       at pr2sets_fla::MainTimeline/save_image_function()

Answer (score 3):

The encode method is static, you need to call it this way.

```
var bytes:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode( bmd );
```